# MVC4 bundle pattern error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm stuck with bundles in MVC4. I have defined bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/maps").Include("~/Scripts/map.*.js"));
```

and scripts

```
map.base.js
map.helper.js
```

This was OK until I have added

```
map.setting.js
```

After that I'm geting error

```
Invalid pattern: 'map.*.js'. Wildcards are only allowed in the last path segment, can contain only one leading or trailing wildcard, and cannot be used with {version}.
```

Parameter name: virtualPaths

Any ideas how to solve this without listing all the files (I'm expecting to add more with "map." prefix)?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just seems to be an annoying limitation of the current Bundle version.

You can write:

```
.Include("~/Scripts/map.*")
```

Of course it may pick up `~/Scripts/map.a.txt`  (not sure, did not test that edge case).  As long as you only have .js resources in the given path, `map.*` is safe.